# Custom post order in some categories (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

On page I set default post sorting by price (desc). I have some categories, where I want to set manual sorting using plugin to do it.
I suppose that my default sorting method determines that I can't do this in other categrories.

How can I change the code to may set a list of categories where I can set the manual sorting of post.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat'            => '20',
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'meta_key'       => 'product_price',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged', 1),
);
query_posts($args);
$posts = get_posts($args);
?>

<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
```

Comment: why using `query_post` and `get_posts` together ?

Comment: try using WP_QUERY

Comment: Maybe I can try "php while" - if cat is '20' i have sorting by price and other categories manual?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable page_attributes for this custom post type. So that you can set the order of these custom post types. It will be in right section of the edit screen of the post.
2. If the category ID is specific where you want to set the custom ordering, Write the WP_Query as follows

> If part

```
// if current category is 20 then this code
$args = array(
    'cat'            => '20',
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged', 1),
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

> Else part

```
// else your code

$args = array(
    'cat'            => '20',
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
    'meta_key'       => 'product_price',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged', 1),
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```